# Mean and Variance of Binomial Random Variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent binomial random variables with parameters $n_1=3$, $n_2=4$, and $p=0.3$ (same $p$ for both), and $Z=X+Y$. What is the mean and variance of $Z$?

Based on my current knowledge, I know that for a Binomial $(n,p)$ random variable, $E(X)=np$ and $Var(X)=np(1-P)$. What I'm confused about is the multiple parameters $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another observation worth mentioning is that because $p$ is the same for both $X$ and $Y$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent, it follows that $Z = X+Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n_1 + n_2, p)$, hence $\operatorname{E}[Z] = (n_1 + n_2)p$ and $\operatorname{Var}[Z] = (n_1 + n_2)p(1-p)$.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

For random variables:

E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)

For **independent** random variables:

Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)